# Jquery append two html pages with different classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, append

Hi i'm confused with the **.append()** and **.html()** function of jquery.

I have this inside of AJAX sucess:

```
success: function(response){

$('#imodal').html('Success!').addClass("flash-success").fadeIn();

$('#imodal').append(response);

}
```

this will basically show a sort of **flash message in a green background** with the class "flash-success", and the **response from a JSON encode** which contains necessary information about the transaction that just happened.

My problem is, the class **"flash-success" is also present in the appended response.**
How do i make the classes of these two different? I tried this:

```
$('#imodal').html('Success!').addClass("flash-success").fadeIn();

$('#imodal').append(response).removeClass("flash-success");
```

but no luck. The appended response is still in green probably having the "flash-success" class.. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You append to a container. The containe has a class. That class will affect the appended content. Where is the confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery **append()** will insert content / element at the end of the container with out replacing its content.
http://api.jquery.com/append/

Where, jQuery **html()** will overwrite the content inside the container with give data and with html formatting
http://api.jquery.com/html/

```
My problem is, the class "flash-success" is also present in the appended response
```

Because you are adding class to the append itself `html('Success!').addClass("flash-success")`

Try:

```
$('#imodal').append(response); // Append the child to element
$('#imodal').addClass("flash-success"); // add class to container
```

Comment: Appending or Inserting new data will not change the class of the container unless you have coded to change.

Comment: the first html should have the class, but the appended should not. how do i do that?

Comment: yah i get it, thanks. I didn't think of it much. What i did was to add another element for the flash message and another different element to the response.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

jQuery .append() method will add the content to the end of element. In your case, "response" will be added to the DOM element with ID "imodal".

If you want the  to be add after the flashing class, then you should append the "response" to another DOM element that locate after the flashing class.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#imodal').append(response).removeClass("flash-success");`
This doesn't remove the class from the appended response, it will look for the class in `#imodal` element which is not there. If your response is html code then you should do something like this : `$(response).removeClass("flash-success");`

Answer (score 0):

**simply you have to add class "flash-success" after appending your response**

```
$("#imodal").append(response)
$("#imodal").addClass("flash-success")
```

**you can get your desired result----**